# Why does this query not return 10 rows?

Tags: mysql

I join two tables, both containing 10 rows, on a unique column.

I know the table `cte` can have duplicates, but then still there should be **10** records in the results, see [DBFIDDLE1](https://dbfiddle.uk/C3fkuh3s)

```
with ints as (
  select 1 as i
  union all select 2
  union all select 3
  union all select 4
  union all select 5
  union all select 6
  union all select 7
  union all select 8
  union all select 9
  union all select 10
),cte as (
   select floor(rand()*10)+1 as x
   from ints
)
select
   i.i, c1.x
from ints i
inner join cte c1 on c1.x=i.i
order by i.i;
```

Query is also available as [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/NsvgvDcL)

(random) Results (because the results are changing):

| i | x |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 8 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 8 | 8 |
| 10 | 2 |

**EDIT:**
Because I am curious for the reason why MySQL is not returning 10 records (without using the `limit`), I created a bug here: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=111852

**EDIT (2023-07-28):**

Reaction from MySQL support on the bug:

> You could avoid the issue by disabling the derived tables merging. Perhaps the issue is produced when  the optimizer merges the derived tables and view references into the outer query block.

```
mysql>  set optimizer_switch  = 'derived_merge=off';
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/XI6Qzw3C) (and [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=111852) for more details)

Comment: I think you need to modify the query to generate a unique set of random values in the "cte" table! use ROW_NUMBER() to assign a unique number to each row!

Comment: @Freeman - The point is that every row in `cte` will have a value between `1` and `10` and so each row should join to exactly one row in `ints` so leading to 10 rows in the result. I presume this is as `rand()` is not deterministic

Comment: Adding `limit 10` in the cte seems to fix it...?

Comment: @Stu   I do not know more place to add `limit 10`, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/zUmQ9-1u  but still not always 10 records

Comment: When I click on that link it gives 10 records. Looks like it materialises it to a temp table from `<auto_key0>` https://dbfiddle.uk/UA_BalzK

Comment: @Luuk there are 10 rows in that linked fiddle? Adding the limit I can't get it to be anything other than 10, moreover i and x are equivalent which you would expect given the join condition. I don't really use mysql much but the behaviour of rand is having some unforeseen impact, which is not unusual I guess.

Comment: Sometimes less than 10 records are shown ( Picture, because it is not always shown: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJJKb.png )

Comment: you've commented out the limit 10

Comment: OK, using `limit 10` will solve the problem of returning less rows than 10. Which is, somewhat, strange to use limit to get more rows....

Comment: The same trick of adding a `TOP` can be often used in SQL Server to get materialisation of CTEs. You can get similar behaviour there

Comment: I'm much more familiar with SQL Server and the effect of row-goals which is why I thought to try the limit in mysql, seems to have similar behaviour; would still be nice to know what it was doing internally to cause the output to vary.

Comment: @Stu - presumably something similar to this https://dbfiddle.uk/y0SKF_hq

Comment: Supposedly there is a hint to get the CTE materialized https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-table-optimization.html - but not working for me so not sure if I am applying it wrong https://dbfiddle.uk/Aeo5TXQE - `LIMIT` is documented as preventing merging anyway though

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes that's a good repro and a certain amount of deja-va